Masive Memory Usage
A few years back I made the switch from Windows to Ubuntu 22.04. I've slowly been learning the Linux platform and have come to truly enjoy it. I've been keeping the distribution up to date. So when Ubuntu 23.x came out I updated to that and then recently updated to 24.04.
While I was using 23.x I switched from using Wayland to X11 so I could use the screensaver as Wayland doesn't support the xscreensaver. It was at this time I noticed that Ubuntu was using an extreme amount of memory. Around 11GB. I figured that was because X11 just uses more than Wayland but when I switched back to Wayland, the system is still using the same amount of memory.
When I check resources in system monitor the math doesn't add up. If I add up all the memory the processes are using it totals to about 4GB. So my question is, where is the unaccounted 7GB of memory going to and why?

Run htop in the terminal and check out which process is consuming so much memory

System buffers tend to use memory, but free it up if a process needs it. See the free vs available entries in a terminal with the free command output.

Show the output of free -mh run in the terminal

also, see https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

First of all I learned something here. I never even thought to use htop but that was the key because it clearly showed what was using all the memory and once I saw what that was (elastic search/kibana) I remembered that I tried to install kibana to try and use my desktop as an SNMP server. But I don't really know what I'm doing and hope that someone posts a video on how to do that.
How embarrassing...
